# How to prove this non-linear system of equations requires complex numbers in the solution?

Tags: complex-numbers, nonlinear-system

I'm trying to solve the equation $$S^2 = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}$$ to conclude at least one coefficient of $S$ will have to be a complex number.  I let $$S = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{bmatrix},$$ from which I obtain

\begin{align*}
  a^2 + bc &= 1\\
  ab + bd  &= 0\\
  ac + dc &= 0\\
  bc + d^2 &= - 1.
\end{align*}

**Question**.  How should I do it?  It seems a found *one* solution in my investigation $4$ below.  Perhaps you could optimize your reading here by going straight to it and then seeing my question in investigation $5$.  (Thank you!)

**Investigation 1**.  I noticed $ab$ and $bd$ either cannot both have the same sign (because they must sum up to zero) or then must both be zero.  But if they're both zero, then either $b = 0$ or $a = d = 0$.  (But I don't know where else to go.  Too many either-or here.)

**Investigation 2**.  I know $bc = 1 - a^2$ and then substituting $bc$ in $bc + d^2 = -1$, I get $d^2 - a^2 = -2$, which looks interesting and implies $(d - a)(d + a) = -2$, but I didn't find a way to deduce a complex solution from there either.

**Investigation 3**.  I know $b$ and $a + d$ cannot both be nonzero because one of the equations in the middle implies $b (a + d) = 0$ and the complex field is an integral domain.  (Similarly for $c$ and $a + d$.)

**Investigation 4**.  From investigation $1$ and $3$, I can conclude that if $b$ is not zero zero then $ab$ and $bd$ would both be zero meaning $a = d = 0$.  So maybe there's a solution here.  Why don't I let $b = 0$ first?  That implies $a = \pm 1$ and $bc = 0$, from which we can deduce that $d^2 = -1$, so $d$ will have to be $\pm \sqrt{-1}$, as desired.

**Investigation 5**.  Because I found one solution in investigation $4$ and it is a complex solution, that doesn't mean that all possible solutions would all be complex.  So I would somehow need to prove that this system has a unique solution, which is the one I found in investigation $4$.

Comment: **2.** $(d-a)(d+a)=-2\implies a+d\ne 0$, then **3.** $b=c=0$, then your **4.** follows that $d^2 = -1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps simpler:

$$Eq. 2:\;ab+bd=0\iff(a+d)b=0\implies b=0\;\;or\;\;a=-d$$

$$(1)\;\;\text{If}\;\;b=0\implies \;Eq. \;4\;\;d^2=-1\implies d=\pm i\in\Bbb C\setminus\Bbb R$$

$$(2)\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\text{If}\;\;a=-d\implies\;Eqs.\; 2,3\;\;\text{are always true and}\;\; Eq. 4\;\;a^2+bc=-1$$

But as remarked by the comment below, this last equation equation is then identical with equation 1, so they contradict each other and thus this case cannot be.

Comment: If $a=-d$, then Eq. 4 $bc+d^2 = -1$ contradicts Eq. 1 $a^2+bc = 1$.

Comment: @peterwhy Completely right you are. I focused in the equations 2,3 that forgot completely to keep an eye on that equation after taking the case $\;a=d\;$

Comment: Your answer is a lecture in a very important principle of mathematical investigation --- conjecture and see what it leads to. I didn't see it, but it was right there.  Thanks for bringing it out.  (Thanks @peterwhy for the team work.)

Answer (score 2):

First if $b$ and $c$ are zero then $S$ is diagonal so the square is the square of the diagonal entries which would imply $d^2=-1$ and we're done. So we can now assume one of them is non-zero which from the middle two equations gives us that $a=-d$ depending on which is non-zero. However we now have that $a^2=d^2$ so this gives us $a^2+bc=1$ and $a^2+bc=-1$ and subtracting one gives us the contradiction $0=2$, so our assumption that either $b$ or $c$ are non-zero is false. This leaves only the diagonal matrices with $a=\pm 1$ and $d = \pm i$ as possibilities.

Comment: That's brilliant.  Thank you so much for bringing in the diagonal observation.  The fact that I selected the other answer does not mean that I did not find your solution more elegant --- because it is more elegant.